# GORM query to find all the records of a table which are not null for its contact field given a name field

Tags: database, sqlite, grails-orm, go-gorm, notnull

I have a table in sqlite which consists of three columns, i.e. Name, Surname and Contact_Number.
The scenario is, that I am given any name(which is present in the database) and I have to find all the records which are related with that name and have Contact_Number "NOT NULL".
(There can be multiple contact numbers for a name, and they are stored each as a different record,
For example:

Name    Surname    Contact_Number
Ajay    Naik       1234
Ajay    Naik       6789
Ajay    Naik       null

So the query in GORM should return Upper two records on the name Ajay.